# Decimal expansion based on slot length summation

Tags: python, algorithm, decimal

I'm trying to create an algorithm to produce a decimal number by certain way.

a) I have an initial number say `i = 2.`

b) Then I have an incremental addition method, say `f(n) { n * 2 }`.

c) Then I have a slot length for digits say `l = 2`, that creates front zeros for small numbers and limits max length of the longer numbers. `2` becomes `02`, `64` is `64`, but `512 = (5)12` where `5` is moved backward on previous slot

d) Max slots is the fourth parameter, `m = 10`

e) Finally I want to compute value by summing up digit from slots and using it as a decimal part of the `0`.

So with given example:

```
i=2
f(n)=n*2
l=2
m=10
```

outcome should be produced in this manner:

step 1)

```
02 04 08 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024
```

step 2)

```
02 04 08 16 32 64
                1 28
                   2 56
                      5 12
                        10 24
```

->

```
slot:     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
computed: 02 04 08 16 32 65 30 61 22 24
```

step 3)

I have a number: `02040816326530612224` or `0.02040816326530612224` as stated on part e).

Note that if max slot is bigger in this example, then numbers on slots `9` and `10` will change. I also want to have part b) as a function, so I can change it to other like `fib(nx) {n1+n2}`.

I prefer Python as a computer language for algo, but anything that is easy to transform to Python is acceptable.

ADDED

This is a function I have managed to create so far:

```
# l = slot length, doesnt work with number > 2...
def comp(l = 2):

    a = []
    # how to pass a function, that produces this list?
    b = [[0, 2], [0, 4], [0, 8], [1, 6], [3, 2], [6, 4], [1, 2, 8], [2, 5, 6], [5, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2, 4], [2, 0, 4, 8]]

    r = 0
    # main algo
    for bb in b:
        ll = len(bb)
        for i in range(0, ll):
            x = r + i - ll + l
            # is there a better way to do following try except part?
            try:
                a[x] += bb[i]
            except IndexError:
                a.append(bb[i])
            # moving bits backward, any better way to do this?
            s = a[x] - 9
            d = 0
            while s > 0:
                d += 1
                a[x] -= 10
                a[x-d] += 1
                s = a[x-d] - 9
        r += l

    return '0.' + ''.join(map(str, a))
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Would you create and show me a python function(s) for described algo?

Comment: On SO you have little chance of getting positive replies to "do it all for me" requests. Downvotes are more likely.

Comment: Ok, ill have a sceleton function ready in a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def doub(n):
    return pow(2, n)

def fibo(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a

def fixed_slot_numbers(f, l, m):
    b = []
    for n in range(1, m):
        a = [int(c) for c in str(f(n))]
        while len(a) < l:
            a.insert(0, 0)
        b.append(a)
    return b

def algo(function, fixed_slot_length = 2, max_slots = 12):
    a = []
    slot_numbers = fixed_slot_numbers(function, fixed_slot_length, max_slots)
    for r, b in enumerate(slot_numbers):
        r *= fixed_slot_length
        slot_length = len(b)
        for bidx in range(0, slot_length):
            aidx = r + bidx - slot_length + fixed_slot_length
            try:
                a[aidx] += b[bidx]
            except IndexError:
                a.append(b[bidx])
            d = 0
            while a[aidx-d] > 9:
                a[aidx-d] -= 10
                d += 1
                a[aidx-d] += 1
    return '0.%s' % ''.join(map(str, a))


algo(doub, 2, 28) -> 0.020408163265306122448979591836734693877551020405424128 = 1/49

algo(fibo, 1, 28) -> 0.112359550561797752808950848 = 10/89
```